# Erro ao iniciar um app em Flutter no Iphone Físico

Tags: ios, mobile, flutter, deploy

Estou tentando rodar um app escrito em Flutter no Iphone físico, quando executo o comando *flutter run* é iniciado o deploy, porém, fica carregando infinitamente. Quando rodo via x-code o erro abaixo é apresentado (Thread 1: signal SIGABRT) e no Iphone a tela permanece branca.

[image: Erro Thread 1: signal SIGABRT]

Já tentei fazer o deploy do app demo do Flutter, que é criado ao comando "flutter create myapp". O erro que aparece é o mesmo.

Espero que possam me auxiliar, agradeço desde já!